# HTML Email - Outlook.com/Hotmail CSS overriding styles

Tags: css, email, html-email, hotmail, outlook.com

I'm working on an email that is having spacing issues between the `<p>` tags in hotmail. I used the

```
.ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
```

but it looks like Hotmail has changed their CSS structure.

I inspected the file and there's [an external CSS](https://a.gfx.ms/wlx_sharedCtrl_sf6yJLkRwuDRl7g9anVpXg2.css) being called that is controlling the paragraph formatting and stripping any inline styles or styles in the head particularly controlling the margin of `<p>`. This CSS is globally giving the paragraphs margins of 1.35em but I want it to be .5em.

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Outlook.com and Hotmail will ignore CSS margin](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), no matter how you try to apply it.

Don't bother with `<p>` tags - just use multiple `<tr>`s in a `<table>`. When you need to space out the content, use a fixed height empty `<td>` in its own `<tr>`.